# Trying to understand variables and basic console commands

Tags: c#, variables, console.writeline

I am working through a basic lesson from Solo Learn and have been messing around with variables. I am trying to figure out how calling strings works and have two simple sequences of code. The first uses the placeholder tags and produces: "x = 400, y = 60".

The second one produces this: "({0} {1} {2} {3}, Hello, , My name is Inigo Montoya , You killed my father. , Prepare to Die.)"

On the second, the program doesn't work unless I use "()" after "output ="

Also I don't understand why it prints the placeholders then the string calls by name, instead of using them as variable references, which doesn't happen in the first method, even if I change it to var.

If I make "output" a string i get the error: "cannot implicity convert string output to string."

Lastly the three "using." lines at the top aren't the ones they usually are when I do windows forms, or even a .NET framework console application, but the basic "hello, world!" didn't seem to work at all when I tried to use .NET framework.

can anyone help clear up this mystery and give me some insight? I feel like I'm really close to understanding the basic concepts going on here.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace PrintingTextSL
{
    class Program
    { 
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
            int x = 400;
            int y = 60;
            int z = 9000;
        
            Console.WriteLine("x = {0}, y = {1}", x, y);
        
       }
   }
}

namespace PrintingTextSL
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            string PoliteGreeting = "Hello, ";
            string Name = "My name is Inigo Montoya ";
            string RelevantPersonalLink = "You killed my father. ";
            string ManageExpectations = "Prepare to Die.";
        
            var output = ("{0} {1} {2} {3}", PoliteGreeting, Name, RelevantPersonalLink, ManageExpectations);
        
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        
        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hover with your mouse over your Console.WriteLines and it will show you that the first one is a WriteLine with string as first parameter and an object array as the second parameter. Whereas the second WriteLine just accepts an object parameter. That is because if you hover over output it’s will show you that output is not a string but a tuple consisting of five strings. You need to tell your program that "{0} {1} {2} {3}" is a format string and the other parameters are the placeholders. You do this by calling `var output = string.Format(…)`. The first WriteLine does this internally.

Comment: I see now the difference between the two. When I try to implement string.Format I get this error: "CS1656 Cannot assign to 'Format' because it is a 'method group'". And when I write "var output = string.Format(...) what is the proper syntax for what I put in parenthesis?

Comment: It’s `var output = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", PoliteGreeting, Name, RelevantPersonalLink, ManageExpectations)`.

Answer (score 2):

The ability to "format" a string using one or more parameter is a feature of the `WriteLine` method of the `Console` class. By the way, you've verified that this works fine:

```
        Console.WriteLine("x = {0}, y = {1}", x, y);
```

However, the second attempt is <strike>an (invalid) expression itself</strike>, not involving any function or method supporting it. (Actually is a valid [tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples), but it has nothing to do with the subject are you asking for.)

If you like, you can do something very similar and totally valid, so called ["string interpolation"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated):

```
        string output = $"{PoliteGreeting} {Name} {RelevantPersonalLink} {ManageExpectations}";
    
        Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Basically you can compose your own string format, and also using the variables (or expressions) directly within the string itself. Just enclose them in brackets.

As specified in the documentation:

> To identify a string literal as an interpolated string, prepend it
> with the $ symbol. You cannot have any white space between the $ and
> the " that starts a string literal.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick! Now I know about interpolated string. So The benefit I saw in using placeholders was that I could tie the placeholder to input if I wanted to allow a selection between four choices for the user to make the string, and trigger a boolean value based on that selection. Is this something I can do if I start with an interpolated string statement?

Answer (score 2):

```
var output = ("{0} {1} {2} {3}", PoliteGreeting, Name, RelevantPersonalLink, ManageExpectations);
```

is just the short for:

```
var output = new Tuple<string,string,string,string,string>("{0} {1} {2} {3}", PoliteGreeting, Name, RelevantPersonalLink, ManageExpectations);
```

to make it work u should then do:

```
Console.WriteLine(output.Item1,output.Item2,output.Item3,output.Item4,output.Item5);
```

Comment: It’s a ValueTuple, not a Tuple.

Comment: Thanks, this one works too! Can you explain why, when I have four items, the program will only work if I include "output.item5"